# How do I use Signals i Django to Calculate Age based on Date entered, if entered at all?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-signals

We do not use Date of Birth as a *mandatory* field during signup. But, in the Model we have an auto-calculate function to arrive at the 'Age' of the user.

So while this works fine when using Django built-in registration mechanism, it fails with custom.

How can Signals be leveraged to check -

1. if DoB was entered?
2. if DoB entered, then calculate Age and Populate *Age Field*?

Thanks in Advance for shring your knowledge.

Regds.

Comment: Please *don't* use signals for this. Exactly what is not working with your custom registration?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this signal works fine. Thank you for your wisdom. Signals is the way to have a clean code. Maybe you want to copy??!

Comment: ```Signals.py``` is used to de-code and create ***events** based action. Use the code.

Comment: here is a list of all problems that arise with signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand where you are comming from. But the process of creation of users should ideally __not be__ a bulk activity. And thank you for sharing. Will keep it mind.

Comment: it is not only about bulk_creates, it is also about getting in an infinite loop, unexpected exceptions (typically resolved with a blanket catch, which is an anti-pattern by itself), delay between creating a user, and linking a profile for example. See for example https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/ and https://www.quora.com/Are-Django-signals-an-anti-pattern It also violates the [*Zen of Python*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) that explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
    if instance.dateBirth:
        
        today = date.today()
        rdelta = relativedelta(today,instance.dateBirth)
        instance.Age = rdelta.years

        if instance.Age > 18: #timedelta(days=18 * 365):

            instance.is_adult = True

            return(instance.is_adult, instance.Age)
        else:
            instance.is_adult = False

            return (instance.is_adult, instance.Age)
```

dont forget to update `__init__.py` and `apps.py`

Answer (score 0):

Storing the age in a field looks like a bad idea: if the record is not updated somehow, or the signals do not run, then the age can get outdated. For example a person might be stored in the database, but if you never save that object again, after the person's birthday, it will still show the old age.

Therefore it is better *not* to store this in a field, and use for example a property to determine this when that is necessary, you can define such model with:

from django.utils.timezone import now

```
class User(models.Model):
    # …
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    # no age or is_adult field

    @property
    def age(self):
        today = now().date()
        dob = self.date_of_birth
        return today.year - dob.year - (today.timetuple()[1:3] < dob.timetuple()[1:3])
    
    @property
    def is_adult(self):
        return self.age >= 18
```

This will thus make it possible to access `.age` and `.is_adult` for a `User` object.